# Select different value in my last table row

Tags: php, mysql

I don't know what's wrong; I check my query but it return the different value.

Here's my table.

```
user_idno  |   func | quest_idno |
----------------------------------
P-001   |    F1     |      1     | 
P-001   |    F1     |      2     |  
P-001   |    F1     |      3     | 
P-001   |    F1     |      4     | 
P-001   |    F1     |      5     |  
P-001   |    F1     |      21    |
```

What I want is select the last row in my questID. So here's my code:

```
$prevQuestion = "SELECT quest_idno FROM engexam_counter 
                                    WHERE user_idno = '$user_id' 
                                    ORDER BY quest_idno DESC LIMIT 0,1";

if ($prevResult=mysqli_query($con,$prevQuestion)){
    $prevCount = mysqli_num_rows($prevResult);

    if($prevCount>0){
        $prevObj=mysqli_fetch_object($prevResult);
        echo $prevQuestID = $prevObj->quest_idno . '<br>';
```

but when I try to echo the output is:

> 5

what I want to get is:

> 21

I also use a subquery and use MAX(id) but the output is the same.

Comment: I bet your `quest_idno` is `char` or `varchar` when it should be a numeric type.

Comment: should also just be `LIMIT 1`

Comment: thanks guys I overlook my structure and yes It is varchar. Thanks @MikeW

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Assumes your 'quest_idno' is char:

```
SELECT MAX(CAST(quest_idno AS UNSIGNED)) as qid FROM engexam_counter WHERE user_idno = '$user_id'
```